# Redirecting base domain to HTTPS, and sub-domains to HTTP

Tags: apache, nginx, url-rewriting

I've been using Apache for a project, and have now decided to convert over to nginx for performance reasons as the project has grown quite a bit.

For this project, we serve our base domain and www sub-domain over HTTPS, but need to serve all other sub-domains over HTTP.

In Apache, I was able to accomplish this with the RewriteEngine doing the following:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect domain and www to HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =mydomain.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

#Redirect wildcard subdomains to HTTP
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.mydomain.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

I have my website about half setup with nginx, and this portion of the configuration has stumped me. How do I go about converting this to work with nginx?

Answer (score 1):

I divided the answer in 4 virtual host. The first two solve the http to https redirect among the main domains. And the second part catches the subdomains and redirects from https to http:

```
# FIRST PART ---------------
# from http to https on main domains                 
server {                                             
  listen 80;                                         
  server_name domain www.domain;                     

  location / {                                       
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;            
  }                                                  
}                                                    

server {
  listen 443 ssl;
  server_name domain www.domain;

  # blah, blah, https and virtualhost configuration                  
}                                                    



# SECOND PART ---------------
# from https to http and others subdomains           
server {                                             
  listen 443 ssl;                                    
  server_name *.domain;                              

  # blah, blah, https configuration                  
  location / {                                       
    return 301 http://$host$request_uri              
  }                                                  
}                                                    

server {                                             
  listen 80;                                         
  server *.domain;                                    
  # virtual with http configuration                  
}
```

Comment: where would I implement a www to non-www redirect with this solution?

Comment: Also, your solution is redirecting everything from http to https. all wildcard subdomains are being sent to SSL.

Comment: In your question you requested www and not www to be handled via SSL. By that I understood that www.domain and domain should by handled SSL (FIRST PART).

Comment: In your question you requested www and not www to be handled via SSL. By that I understood that www.domain and domain should by handled SSL (FIRST PART). First virtual host redirects all http (www.domain or domain) to https on second virtual host (www.domain or domain).

third virtual host is declared to redirect all the SSL to http, it doesn't do anything but redirect to fourth virtual host. The "server *.domain" doesn't match every subdomain. "www.domain" is declared on first and second. "server *.domain" works as a "catch all" virtual host for the remaining matches.